# Is it not valid now the 'authenticateWithBiometrics' in local-auth plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication

I'm using the plugin 'local-auth'. I got the source code that opens a dialog for fingerpring authentication. the method name is 'authenticateWithBiometrics' but it occures an error like this. => The method 'authenticateWithBiometrics' isn't defined for the type 'LocalAuthentication'.

Is there a replaceable method in the plug-in? then, please let me know. Thanks.

```
authenticated = await _localAuthentication.authenticateWithBiometrics(...)
```

Comment: I think you just need to full restart code, Rerun your application

Answer (score 1):

`authenticateWithBiometrics` change with `authenticate`. It will work well.